# Movieclips inside movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, arguments, movieclip

I have created a movieclip with some buttons inside it divided in 5 categories (frutoN). Each categorie will have a different ammount of buttons (frutoLC).

The Variable frutoLN is the instance name for that specifc buttom (ie: bt0101 or bt0532);

So, here is the question: 
the variable frutoLN must have what kind of argument? I've tried :String and :MovieClip and none of them work at all.

```
for (frutoLC=1; frutoLC<=frutoL;frutoLC++){ 
        var frutoLN;
        frutoLN = "this.cena.cenaDentro.bt"+frutoN+""+frutoLC;
        trace ("frutoLN = "+frutoLN);
        frutoLN.visible = true;
    }
```

Sorry for my english and I hope I've made myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

In your code above, the `frutoLN` variable will be a `String` object. To access the `MovieClip` you are looking for, you need to do something along these lines:

```
for (var frutoLC:uint = 1; frutoLC <= frutoL; frutoLC++) {
    var frutoLN:MovieClip = this.cena.cenaDentro["bt" + frutoN.toString() + frutoLC.toString()];
    frutoLN.visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Or var frutoLN:SimpleButton as he is mentioning buttons.